# run security node repl in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, read-eval-print-loop

I want to try to run the node repl in the discord bot.
So I have to concern some untrusted code in the repl.

here is repl code.

```js
const repl = require('repl');
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream');

const datas = [];

const readable = new Readable({
    read(size) {
        return true;
    }
});
const writable = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const value = chunk.toString();
        if (value !== "") {
            datas.push(value);
        }
        callback();
    }
});

const { context } = repl.start({
    prompt: "",
    input: readable,
    output: writable,
    useGlobal: false,
    replMode: repl.REPL_MODE_STRICT
});

function run(code) {
    readable.push(code);

    const strList = datas.slice();
    datas.length = 0;
    
    return strList;
}

exports.run = run;
```

this code have security problem :

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('.env', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

console.log(1);
```

I'm trying to apply this code to a discord bot, and this code prints out the bot token.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you update with the error message? Also I am having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to accomplish here, but console logging the `.env` file will always lead to security issues.

Comment: I have created an `.env` file in my project path. And the file contains the bot token value, which is retrieved through the dotenv library.

Comment: so why are you then reading the `.env` file in memory and logging it into the console?

Comment: need to run discord bot

Comment: im sorry i do not understand your response, please see the [dotenv package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to learn its usage

Comment: What I want now is to prevent access to those files in repl.